# Regex to remove the whole outer parent pattern but still preserving the data inside child pattern. Nested Patterns

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove a specific pattern which starts with either `\(` or with `\\(` and ends with `/)` or `//)`. There may or may not be a space before and after the pattern i.e the pattern can be in the starting or on the end too.

But the real problem is that There is very useful data inside a child pattern which starts with `\text { preserve this data }` too and I want to preserve that thing.

For example:

```
this is my text \( delete it x+y I do not care \text { Preserve this } whatever is here I do not care \text {preserve this also} \) this is outside text
```

SO the result should be something like :

```
this is my text Preserve this preserve this also this is outside text
```

Basically this is `MathPix` markdown and I want to remove it except `\text`. I can remove these `\tags` via using

`s = re.sub(r"\\[a-z]{3,}",' ',s)`

and then can use `\\text {(.*?)\}` to find the `\text { asdas }` **( but I do not know how to recover/keep it)**

but it'll create a problem for me that apart from the tags, there is a lot of garbage data inside which will be unidentifiable for me later. I can run a loop where I see `\(` or `\\(` and then an inner loop for `\text {` but the problem is there can be any number of `\text`. It'll be very hard for me to do it.

I have a JAVA code which my friend suggested for me  but I do not know what would be the Python equivalent for it and also I have not used this on corner cases. The Java code is something like:

```
Pattern.compile("(?=((\\\\text \\{)(.*?)(\\})))")
```

I'll really appreciate any help. I have little or no experience with groups and literally no idea about how to preserve inner things like this.

**EDIT**:
A very typical example would be:

**\( \begin{array}{ll}\text { Set A } & \text { Set B } \ \text { 1. Adenine } & \text { a. } C_{5} N_{5} H_{5} O \ \text { 2. Guanine } & \text { b. } C_{4} N_{2} H_{4} O_{2} \ \text { 3. Uracil } & \text { c. } C_{5} N_{5} H_{5} \ \text { 4. Thymine } & \text { d. } C_{5} N_{2} H_{6} O_{2}\end{array} ) ( \mathbf{A} ) ( 1-c ; 2-a ; 3-d ; 4-b ) B. ( 1-c ; 2-b ; 3-d ; 4-e ) c. ( 1-b ; 2-c ; 3-d ; 4-a ) D. ( 1-c ; 2-a ; 3-b ; 4-d \)**

or

**\( \begin{array}{ll}\text { 34. Climbing roots occur in } & \text { [APMEE 1996; CBSE PMT 1999] }\end{array} \)**

or

**\( \begin{array}{ll}\text { 21. Mesophyll is usually differentiated in } & \text { ICBSE'02] }\end{array} \)**

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'\s*\\+\((.*?)\\+\)', lambda x: " ".join(re.findall(r'\\[a-z]{3,}\s*{([^{}]*)}', x.group(1))), s)`

Comment: Is it necessary to use a regular expression? Otherwise you can loop over the string and count the elements `(` and `)` and append each letter to the string you want to keep.

Comment: It fails for : ```\( \begin{array}{ll}\text { Set A } & \text { Set B } \\ \text { 1. Adenine } & \text { a. } C_{5} N_{5} H_{5} O \\ \text { 2. Guanine } & \text { b. } C_{4} N_{2} H_{4} O_{2} \\ \text { 3. Uracil } & \text { c. } C_{5} N_{5} H_{5} \\ \text { 4. Thymine } & \text { d. } C_{5} N_{2} H_{6} O_{2}\end{array} \) \( \mathbf{A} \) \( 1-c ; 2-a ; 3-d ; 4-b \) B. \( 1-c ; 2-b ; 3-d ; 4-e \) c. \( 1-b ; 2-c ; 3-d ; 4-a \) D. \( 1-c ; 2-a ; 3-b ; 4-d \)```

Comment: @mosc9575 I am working with STEM data and that too more than 150K questions. It covers almost every symbol in different positions and locations.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for helping. I saw your answer yesterday too but it failed for cases. Can you please help me.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the wanted output to every example.

Comment: So, what is wrong with that new example? See https://ideone.com/s0vacs, it seems to work **as per your requirements**.

Comment: Sorry! My bad. You can't use the string as it is. You have to pass it like `r"string here"`. I passed it as it is. @WiktorStribiżew Can you please explain it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'll be using it in a loop so I won't be able to manually put `r` before everystring. Can you please help me out with this one? Thanks a lot for your answer. This is exactly what I wanted to have. Sorry that I'm looking like a complete noob here.

Comment: You do not need `r` when you define patterns from external data. Just make sure you send the right text.

Comment: I posted an answer with the solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew For the string `f current \( \boldsymbol{I}_{1}=\mathbf{3} \boldsymbol{A} \sin \omega \boldsymbol{t} \) and \( \boldsymbol{I}_{2}= \)
\( 4 A \cos \omega t, \) then \( I_{3} \) is
A \( \cdot 5 a \sin \left(\omega t+53^{\circ}\right) \)
B. \( 5 a \sin \left(\omega t+37^{\circ}\right) \)
c. \( 5 a \sin \left(\omega t+45^{\circ}\right) \)
D. \( 5 a \sin \left(\omega t+30^{\circ}\right) \)` , it is giving me **f currenti 3 a t andi then is a b. c. d.**  but I wanted **f current** only because there is no `\text` or `\\text`. I wanted to remove everything inside the brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'\s*\\+\((.*?)\\+\)', lambda x: " ".join(re.findall(r'\\[a-z]{3,}\s*{([^{}]*)}', x.group(1))), s)
```

The first expression finds

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\\+\(` - 1+ `\` chars and then a `(`
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\\+\)` - 1+ `\` chars and then a `)`.

The second expression finds the following pattern matches in the found Group 1 matches:

- `\\` - a `\` char
- `[a-z]{3,}` - three or more lowercase ASCII letters
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `{` - a  `{` char
- `([^{}]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `}` - a `}` char.

All Group 1 matches found are joined with a space and this is the replacement for the outer `re.sub`.
See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/s0vacs):

```py
import re
s = r'''this is my text \( delete it x+y I do not care \text { Preserve this } whatever is here I do not care \text {preserve this also} \) this is outside text'''
print( re.sub(r'\s*\\+\((.*?)\\+\)', lambda x: " ".join(re.findall(r'\\[a-z]{3,}\s*{([^{}]*)}', x.group(1))), s) )
# => this is my text Preserve this  preserve this also this is outside text
 
s = r'''\( \begin{array}{ll}\text { Set A } & \text { Set B } \\ \text { 1. Adenine } & \text { a. } C_{5} N_{5} H_{5} O \\ \text { 2. Guanine } & \text { b. } C_{4} N_{2} H_{4} O_{2} \\ \text { 3. Uracil } & \text { c. } C_{5} N_{5} H_{5} \\ \text { 4. Thymine } & \text { d. } C_{5} N_{2} H_{6} O_{2}\end{array} \) \( \mathbf{A} \) \( 1-c ; 2-a ; 3-d ; 4-b \) B. \( 1-c ; 2-b ; 3-d ; 4-e \) c. \( 1-b ; 2-c ; 3-d ; 4-a \) D. \( 1-c ; 2-a ; 3-b ; 4-d \)'''
print( re.sub(r'\s*\\+\((.*?)\\+\)', lambda x: " ".join(re.findall(r'\\[a-z]{3,}\s*{([^{}]*)}', x.group(1))), s) )
# => array  Set A   Set B   1. Adenine   a.   2. Guanine   b.   3. Uracil   c.   4. Thymine   d.  arrayA B. c. D.
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. I used your function and irt is working very well but it only works well with raw strings. It means it'll give different with `"string"` and `r"string"`. Since my string is in inside a variable, I can not use `r" "` so I found a way to deal with it using `repr(string_var)` and it works very with all the cases. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @Deshwal Glad you found a workaround for your strings. Regex is a *string (or text) pattern* that is used to search for its matches inside other texts, literal strings. It is agnostic of all the intricacies of how a string (or text) can be represented inside the code. You must be having issues related to the API that serves the text data, or the consumer code, or both, you should check that and fix if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Will check that.

Comment: @Deshwal Sorry, this is not clear.`3 a t andi then is a b. c. d` are not inside escaped parentheses, so they are there in the result. Your current question does not describe such a case, and the requirements are to only remove strings in between `\(...\)` that are not preceded with ``\text``.

Comment: They are not inside the parentheses, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EJH84l/1).

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/EJH84l/2 and https://ideone.com/Gtzg8f, the output is `f current and then is A B. c. D.`. If it is not what you need, please update the question with the real requirements.

Comment: If You use `re.sub(r'\s*\\+\((.*?)\\+\)', lambda x: " ".join(re.findall(r'\\[a-z]{3,}\s*{([^{}]*)}', x.group(1))), s)` to the string `Determine \\( \\boldsymbol{V}(\\boldsymbol{x}) \\)\nA . \\( 20 x \\)\nB . \\( -20 x \\)\nc. \\( 10 x \\)\nD. \\( -10 x \\)`, it'll give you result as **DetermineV x\nA .\nB .\nc.\nD.**. Do You see the extra `V` added to `Determine`? It came from `\\boldsymbol{V}`. Do you get my Point now?

Comment: @Deshwal Sorry, [I get](https://ideone.com/hwtMJG) `Determine\nA .\nB .\nc.\nD.`

Comment: My bad. I used your old code. `lambda x: " ".join(re.findall(r'\\[a-z]{3,}\s*{([^{}]*)}'` but the new code is `lambda x: " ".join(re.findall(r'\\text\s*{([^{}]*)}'`

Comment: @Deshwal Correct. I use `[a-z]{3,}` in the initial regex because you wrote "*I can remove these \tags via using `s = re.sub(r"\\[a-z]{3,}",' ',s)`*". I always tend to keep as close to the original attempt as possible, especially when the user says it works for them.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. Sorry that it was my mistake and took your time.